# Error: Syntax - Html to RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a _form and in this _form I am putting one icon in front some fields.

I want wich when mouse hovers over it, it displays a tooltip. The text is there in translate file:

```
..
t('messages.issue_tittle_placeholder')
..
```

I can do this using only html, but I want do this using RoR.

```
<div class="clearfix">
<%= f.label :title %>
  <div class="icon-question_enabled"  rel="tooltip"      
  title="Keaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa">
</div>
```

I tried to this:

```
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= image_tag('icons/question_enabled.png', class=> "tooltip-help") %>
```

Someone can help me?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your html snippet, your icon is just a `<div>` with a css class that has a sprite background instead of an `<img>`. You should do:

```
<%= f.label :title %>
<%= content_tag(:div, nil, class: 'icon-question_enabled', rel: :tooltip, title: "Keaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa") %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is off. For > Ruby 1.9 it should be:

```
<%= image_tag('icons/question_enabled.png', class: "tooltip-help") %>
```

else < 1.8

```
<%= image_tag('icons/question_enabled.png', :class => "tooltip-help") %>
```

Comment: It should be either `:class => '...'` or `class: '...'` as here. The former is Ruby 1.8 syntax, the latter Ruby 1.9.